# How can I call jquery without window object in reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm not sure if this has been asked before or anybody has encountered the same issue on reactjs.

below is my trouble scenario.

1. create-react-app test -> this create 'test' folder and initialize project.
2. cd test -> going into test(project) folder.
3. add jquery cdn into public/index.html -> I will use jquery.
4. make some code using '$' on src/App.js -> in componentDidMount function.
5. npm run start -> error occued ($ is not defined)

In this situation, if i make jquery code with 'window' object, error not occured and everything goes well. (ex. window.$("#id"))

of course I can call jquery with window object, but I think this is not efficient and not looks good.

How can I call jquery without window object?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your case jQuery is not in node_modules when the react code is compiled. You should run `npm install jquery`.

If I can give an advice, it's not a good thing to use jQuery inside a react app.